# Lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Stuck with error:

```
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

For a simple example, let's try to get an object from database using entity framework without actually knowing its type:

```
private DbContext db;
private dynamic test(dynamic entity)
{
    return db.Set(entity.GetType()).First(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You might try http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use generics to do this, rather than `dynamic`:

```
private DbContext db;
private T test<T>(T entity)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    return db.Set<T>().First(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
}
```

Have a `BaseEntity` that has an `Id` property, to ensure that the given entity has an Id.

Comment: Yep, this solves the given example, but I need to stick with dynamic.

Comment: @Wonder Why you want to stick with dynamic?

Comment: @Wonder Odds are you don't.  It's designed for interopping with dynamic languages, which you're not doing.  When working with EF it's almost certainly not the right tool for the job.

Comment: This is a recursive function and I don't know the type for the next iteration.

Comment: @Wonder That's not really enough information for me to help you solve the problem.  Perhaps you should ask a new question with your actual problem, so you can get some help solving it.

Comment: The actual problem doesn't really matter here. I want to understand how to use lambla expressions with dynamic objects.

Comment: @Wonder You can't do this, basically, as the error message is telling you.  Without knowing the details of your *actual* problem there is no possible way to solve it.